# PHP - aria-current not display

Tags: php, html, css

I have a file, **heard.php** where have all PHP code, here is the PHP code which I think making the problem:

```
<nav class="link_wechsel">
 <ul>
  <li><a <?php if ($current_page=="1"): ?>aria-current="page" <?php endif ?> href="prove-1.php">1</a></li>
  <li><a <?php if ($current_page=="2"): ?>aria-current="page" <?php endif ?> href="prove-2.php">2</a></li>
  <li><a <?php if ($current_page=="3"): ?>aria-current="page" <?php endif ?> href="prove-3.php">3</a></li>
 </ul>
</nav>
```

and here is all Code from the **heard.php** file:

```
<?php  
header("Content-Type: text/html; Charset=utf-8");
mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
error_reporting(E_ALL);

?>

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
 <title>header-beispiel</title>
</head>
<style>
.link_wechsel ul {

  list-style-type: none;
  margin-left: 340px;
}

.link_wechsel li { display: inline; }

.link_wechsel a {

  display: inline;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  background-color: #FE2E64;
  color: black;
  padding: 8px;
  opacity: 0.5;
  font-family: Times New Roman;
}

.link_wechsel a:hover { background-color: #9f9e9e; }

.link_wechsel a.[aria-current=page] {

  background-color: green;
}

</style>
<body>
<header>
</header>
<nav class="link_wechsel">
  <ul>
   <li><a <?php if ($current_page=="1"): ?>aria-current="page" <?php endif ?> href="beispiel-1.php">1</a></li>
   <li><a <?php if ($current_page=="2"): ?>aria-current="page" <?php endif ?> href="beispiel-2.php">2</a></li>
   <li><a <?php if ($current_page=="3"): ?>aria-current="page" <?php endif ?> href="beispiel-3.php">3</a></li>
  </ul>
 </nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Then I have three files where display this code, Prove-1.php, Prove-2.php and Prove-3.php, here the Code:

```
<?php  
$current_page = "1";
require 'header.php';

header("Content-Type: text/html; Charset=utf-8");
mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
?>

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
 <title>prove-1</title>
</head>
<body>
 <h3>Page 1</h3>
</body>
</html>
```

On all Three File I have identical Code, only to change $**current_page = "1";** , with **$current_page = "2";** and **$current_page = "3";**.. a Screenshot how to see the Page , [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wIU1C.png)..

As your can see, the color not change of the page number that is currently selected.

The CSS Code, which say does it...

```
.link_wechsel a.[aria-current=page] { background-color: green; }
```

Can someone please anyone help me and found a solution from my problem, Thanks!

Comment: Your question is a little hard to understand. Do you just want to change the color of the page number that is currently selected?

Comment: yes , I wish this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the Problem because the color not change of the page number that is currently selected .

That Problem was on CSS .

I wrote,

```
.link_wechsel a.[aria-current=page] { background-color: green; }
```

when I would to do

```
.link_wechsel a[aria-current=page] { background-color: green; }
```

**without** the Point after **a** .
Because **aria-current** is a [attribute](https://tink.uk/using-the-aria-current-attribute/) and  **page** its Value , therefore the **a** tag , [not need](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp) a Point .
How to [see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y7eEM.png) now without Point...